# Can not re-deploy after moving 3 apps into one folder

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

I moved 3 Node.js apps into a folder in the Web IDE because I wanted to logically group them, not necessarily to change the deployment.
All three apps have their own URL.

Apparently the deployment now works for all 3 apps combined.

Error after clicking on the deploy-arrow:

```
"An app was not successfully detected by any available buildpack"
```

I adapted the launch configuration:

- added the services
- added "npm start"

Still I get this error.

One of the apps does not have a manifest.yml.

When I click on app.js, I sometimes get the following error (in a big red pop-up window):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <style> body{ margin:0px; padding:0px; background-color: #ffffff; color:#000; font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,Tahoma,sans-serif; } #content { font-size: 1em; margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em; padding: 1em; } h4.basichead { font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,Tahoma,sans-serif; } p { padding-top: .5em; } ul { line-height: 1.3em; } a:link { color: #c00000 } a:visited { color: #c00000 } #page {
border: 7px; padding: 7px } #box {
....
```

Log:

```
Updated app with guid 998e32e6-3f4f-4743-8e36-f8cd4c0961bb ({"name"=>"ACP", "command"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "instances"=>1, "memory"=>1024, "environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})
Updated app with guid 998e32e6-3f4f-4743-8e36-f8cd4c0961bb ({"route"=>"8e8a376d-479e-4b4f-921e-932e40fd569f"})
Updated app with guid 998e32e6-3f4f-4743-8e36-f8cd4c0961bb ({"console"=>true, "state"=>"STOPPED"})
Got staging request for app with id 998e32e6-3f4f-4743-8e36-f8cd4c0961bb
Updated app with guid 998e32e6-3f4f-4743-8e36-f8cd4c0961bb ({"console"=>true, "state"=>"STARTED"})
-----> Downloaded app package (6.6M)
encountered error: An app was not successfully detected by any available buildpack
```

Unfortunately I can not move the apps back to the root directory either, for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error `An app was not successfully detected by any available buildpack` because Bluemix cannot decide what kind of application you are trying to deploy. Each buildpack has it's own detect script and none of them fit the bill for your project structure of 3 Node.js apps/folders.

I would suggest trying to place a single `manifest.yml` file at the root of your project (or where you run `cf push`) that tells cloud foundry your intentions.

You can specify multiple applications to be pushed at once. An example manifest.yml:

```
---
# this manifest deploys two applications
# apps are in flame and spark directories
# flame and spark are in fireplace
# cf push should be run from fireplace
applications:
- name: spark
  host: flint-99
  path: ./spark/
- name: flame
  host: burnin-77
  path: ./flame/
```

More information about pushing multiple applications to Cloud Foundry [Here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#multi-apps).